# External monitor doesn't work (no signal) on Ubuntu 21.10 - Intel Iris Xe graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, monitor, 21.10

I have an issue with my external monitor which doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.10 with 5.17.2 kernel on it.

It seems to be detected in "Displays" section in settings, but when I try to use enable it in these settings then my laptop screen just goes black and settings are "reverted" to the situation where only "built-in" screen is used.

[image: Display settings]

Monitor is a 34" Xiaomi Mi Gaming monitor. I connect it to HDMI port.

The issue initially also happened on Ubuntu 20.04 with 5.13 kernel (or something like this). So I tried updating Ubuntu and kernel to latest version which didn't help at all.

It doesn't seem to be a hardware issue. I have a dual boot on this machine with Windows 10 running on second partition and there are no issues with the monitor.

Computer is a Dell with Intel i5 11th gen with Intel Iris Xe Graphics integrated graphics.

Secure boot is off.

Additional Drivers:

[image: Additional Drivers]

Showing some logs below:

(Results of $ sudo lshw -c video, $ xrandr --query, $ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA", $ uname -r, $ inxi -Fxz, $ inxi -G, $ glxinfo -B)

```
$ sudo lshw -c video

*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:175 memory:601e000000-601effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

$ xrandr --query

Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  

$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915

$ uname -r 
5.17.2-051702-generic

$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Kernel: 5.17.2-051702-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Latitude 3420 v: N/A serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0MC6DP v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.15.1 date: 02/15/2022 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 54.0 Wh (100.0%) condition: 54.0/54.0 Wh (100.0%) volts: 17.1 min: 15.0 model: BYD DELL WV3K817 
           status: Full 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1145G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache: L2: 8 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 23961 
           Speed: 539 MHz min/max: 400/4400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 539 2: 985 3: 1141 4: 1078 5: 792 6: 1083 7: 1030 8: 650 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 0000:00:02.0 
           Device-2: Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-6:7 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 compositor: gnome-shell driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Dell driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3 
           Device-2: GN Netcom Jabra EVOLVE 20 MS type: USB driver: jabra,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 3-4:3 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.17.2-051702-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 0000:00:14.3 
           IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Dell driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 
           bus-ID: 0000:2b:00.0 
           IF: enp43s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: br-16c04ee947c8 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:10 
           Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd v: 0.6 bus-ID: 0000:00:0e.0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 17.41 GiB (3.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: BC711 NVMe 512GB size: 476.94 GiB temp: 38.9 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 229.34 GiB used: 17.07 GiB (7.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-2 mapped: ubuntu-root 
           ID-2: /boot size: 574.6 MiB used: 243.4 MiB (42.4%) fs: ext3 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6 
           ID-3: /boot/efi size: 146 MiB used: 101.5 MiB (69.5%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 2.54 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/dm-1 mapped: ubuntu-swap 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 301 Uptime: 41m Memory: 38.93 GiB used: 3.34 GiB (8.6%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A 
           Packages: 1795 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 inxi: 3.3.06 

$ inxi -G 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.21.1.2 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 

$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) (0x9a49)
    Version: 21.2.6
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: Please clarify your OS/release, as you mention one release, but a kernel that isn't used by that release. Are you using Ubuntu ?

Comment: Hi, I placed info about the system in "code" section. Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear. System:    Kernel: 5.17.2-051702-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri)

Comment: Hello. Like @guiverc has already said that is not a supported kernel in ANY release of Ubuntu. That makes it off topic on this site. Not even the yet to be released 22.04 version of Ubuntu will use that on first release.

Comment: I had the same problem when I was on 5.14 something kernel. Does it make any difference?

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. This issue randomly started happening for me one day after I booted my PC. Was on 5.14 generic kernel, I upgraded to 5.17 OEM to see if it would maybe work, but it does not. I have Iris Xe, HDMI, Gigabyte monitor. Plugging in/out the monitor with the HDMI cable triggers no dmesg messages.

Comment: I got this to work by using a USB-C to HDMI dongle